# Entity Fields has no Affect on the Returned Response in NodeJS NestJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am creating an entity for each of my modules where I specify the fields that need to be returned using MySQL DB.

although I am specifying that the return type is of type SomeEntity, if I remove fields from the entity class the response does not change. **even thought i have iso2 and iso3 commented out they still appear in the response.**

Why is that?

What am I doing wrong?

here is my code:

ApiReponse DTO:

```
export interface ApiResponse<T> {
  msg?: string;
  statusCode?: number;
  data?: T;
}
```

country entity:

```
export class CountryEntity {
  id         : number;
  name       : string;
  region     : string;
  subregion  : string
  phone_code : number;
  status     : number
  // iso2       : string;
  // iso3       : string;
}
```

country repository:

```
import { CountryEntity } from "./country.entity";
import { MySQlRepository } from "../../configs/mysql.repository";

export class CountryRepository extends MySQlRepository {

  async fetchAllCountries(): Promise<CountryEntity[]> {
    try {
      const sqlStatement = `
      SELECT * FROM countries;`;
      const [rows] = await this.query(sqlStatement);
      return rows;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }

}
```

country service:

```
export class CountryService {
  constructor(
    private readonly countryRepository: CountryRepository
  ) {}

  async fetchAllCountries(): Promise<ApiResponse<CountryEntity[]>> {
    const countries = await this.countryRepository.fetchAllCountries();
    if (countries) {
      return {
        msg: 'All countries fetched successfully.',
        statusCode: '200',
        data: countries
      };
    } else {
      return {
        msg: 'Unable to retrieve countries.',
        statusCode: '404',
      };
    }
  }
}
```

controller:

```
@Controller('country')
export class CountryController {
  constructor(
    private readonly countryService: CountryService
  ) {}

  @Get('all-countries')
  async fetchAllCountries(): Promise<ApiResponse<CountryEntity[]>> {
    return await this.countryService.fetchAllCountries();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you also add `this.query(sqlStatement)` method

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is nothing else than a type system added on top of JS. This means that it's still JS and what has added is some types annotations that help your code IDE shout at you went you  seems to be doing the wrong thing thereby avoiding runtime errors.

In JS this code will return all the fields of the table countries of your database. Comming back to TS you code editor wouldn't complain because your `query` request is of type `any` which is assimilated to any type include `CountryEntity[]` and somehow fouls the editor but still, nothing has changed.

Here are 03 ways you can resolve this issue:

**1. Destructuring:** use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to remove the unwanted elements. uncomment `iso2` and `iso3` and set them as optional

```
export class CountryEntity {
  id         : number;
  name       : string;
  region     : string;
  subregion  : string
  phone_code : number;
  status     : number
  iso2?       : string;
  iso3?       : string;
}
```

then do this:

```
 async fetchAllCountries(): Promise<ApiResponse<CountryEntity[]>> {
    const countries = await this.countryRepository.fetchAllCountries();
    if (countries) {
      return {
        msg: 'All countries fetched successfully.',
        statusCode: '200',
        data: countries.map(({iso2, iso3, ...country}) => country)
      };
    } else {
      return {
        msg: 'Unable to retrieve countries.',
        statusCode: '404',
      };
    }
  }
```

**2. JavaScript native delete API:** [JS delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) removes a key and its value from an object. Here's a utils function I encapsulated this API in.

```
export function excludeKeys<T, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  keys: K[]
): Omit<T, K> {
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    delete obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
}
```

Here's how you use it:

```
 async fetchAllCountries(): Promise<ApiResponse<CountryEntity[]>> {
    const countries = await this.countryRepository.fetchAllCountries();
    if (countries) {
      return {
        msg: 'All countries fetched successfully.',
        statusCode: '200',
        data: countries.map(country => excludeKeys(country, ['iso2', 'iso3']))
      };
    } else {
      return {
        msg: 'Unable to retrieve countries.',
        statusCode: '404',
      };
    }
  }
```

**3. Serialization:** use [`class-transformer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer) (and even [`class-validator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator)) npm packages to serialize returned data.

```
import { Exlude } from 'class-transformer';
export class CountryEntity {
   id         : number;
   name       : string;
   region     : string;
   subregion  : string
   phone_code : number;
   status     : number;
   
   @Exclude()
   iso2       : string;
   
   @Exclude()
   iso3       : string;
   
   constructor(props: CountryEntity) {
      Object.assign(this, props)
   }
}
```

and your `country.service.ts` will be

```
export class CountryService {
  constructor(
    private readonly countryRepository: CountryRepository
  ) {}

  async fetchAllCountries(): Promise<ApiResponse<CountryEntity[]>> {
    const countries = await this.countryRepository.fetchAllCountries();
    if (countries) {
      return {
        msg: 'All countries fetched successfully.',
        statusCode: '200',
        data: countries.map(country => new CountryEntity(country))
      };
    } else {
      return {
        msg: 'Unable to retrieve countries.',
        statusCode: '404',
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the class transformer method did not work. i am still getting the iso2 and iso3 after using @Exclude

Comment: Please make sure you added the `@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)` decorator to your method controller if you're using [nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization#exclude-properties) otherwise use the `classToPlain` and `plainToClass` methods of the `class-transformer` to achieve the same goal. check examples [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer?tab=readme-ov-file#methods)